# Nuevo comportamiento del indicador de Pending Reviews

Tags: bug, meta, colas-de-revisión

Como algunos de vosotros habréis notado (espero), desde hace algunas semanas el indicador de las colas de revisión se comporta de manera distinta.

Los cambios se explican en este hilo de Meta:
[What criteria should we use to determine which review queue indicator a site will have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305893/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil)

Y nos afectan porque fuimos uno de los *stacks* escogidos para probar los nuevos parámetros.

Sin embargo, al menos en mi opinión, estos cambios no están funcionando del todo bien:

- A veces sucede que el icono de la barra superior no tiene el punto rojo, pero si le haces clic sí que aparecen colas con el punto gris de elementos pendientes.
- Y otras veces sucede lo contrario: el icono tiene un enorme punto rojo pero, si accedes a las colas, no hay nada que revisar:
  [image: sdad]

Estos fallos han sido ya reportados en respuestas al hilo anterior (ver por ejemplo [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306374/362105)), pero de momento lo único que me han propuesto ha sido ["pedir en el chat a la gente que revise las colas"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305893/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil#comment996985_306374), para que las colas se limpien antes y deje de salirme el indicador.

Vale, a ver... Yo no tengo problema en avisar por el chat de que revisemos las colas, pero no creo que sea la solución más adecuada :D

Si os pasa lo mismo y estáis de acuerdo en que la funcionalidad debería revisarse, os animo a pasaros por el hilo de Meta arriba indicado, para dejar vuestra opinión y animarles a que le den otra vuelta al tema.

Comment: Los bugs se recomienda que se escriban en inglés, para que si algún desarrollador se pasa por este Meta lo pueda entender.

Comment: En cuanto al tema en sí: sí, ha habido muchos cambios, pero la esencia es que para nosotros todo sigue más o menos igual :) Con falsos positivos de vez en cuando. No sé si es lo mismo, pero anteriormente dijeron que el botoncito rojo se iluminaba si hacía más de una hora que no lo habías clicado.

Comment: Hay distintos elementos que confluyen aquí: los permisos de cada uno (bug: [Me avisa de sugerencias de edición de wikis de etiqueta pese a que no puedo acceder a ellas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3187/83)), lo costoso de consultar los datos en tiempo real (bug en principio resuelto: [¿Por qué me aparecen tareas pendientes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/837/83)) que los lleva a utilizar cacheo.

Comment: Even after reading the linked information from Meta i am still not clear (a) what the problem was (b) what the solution is (c) whether it is working as intended (d) why it is so irritating.

Comment: I actually don't see the icon right now (not the red dot, but the review icon). Either I never noticed that sometimes it is not displayed or something is wrong. Maybe one developer clicked the wrong button... I'll create a bug if I keep not seeing the reviews icon tonight.

Comment: @Diego Just now (1000 UTC on Friday 2 March 2018) there was no red button on the icon although when I looked further there were red buttons alongside two queues. I had not been on-line for more than 12 hours.