# Deberíamos revisar el comportamiento del indicador de Pending Reviews?

Tags: discusión, colas-de-revisión

Iba a crear una pregunta tipo [bug](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) para el indicador de *Pending Reviews* en las colas de revisión, pero como me sonaba haber tenido problemas con esta funcionalidad en el pasado he mirado posts antiguos y resulta que hace casi dos años se introdujo un [nuevo comportamiento al indicador de *Pending Reviews*.](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2848/5481) El cambio tiene como resultado que el indicador no se comporta como esperamos; del anterior hilo solo podemos extraer que

> Estos fallos han sido ya reportados en respuestas al hilo anterior (ver por ejemplo [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306374/356575)), pero de momento lo único que me han propuesto ha sido "pedir en el chat a la gente que revise las colas", para que las colas se limpien antes y deje de salirme el indicador.

[image: screenshot with the red circle]

Dado que hace poco establecimos una [nueva estrategia sobre las colas de revisión](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3260/5481), el post sobre el (mal) comportamiento del indicador de *Pending reviews* tiene ya casi dos años con cero respuestas, y no puedo poner una recompensa para reabrir el debate (por tratarse de una pregunta en Meta, donde no se permiten recompensas), pregunto:

¿Hay algo que podamos hacer para que no salga el indicador de *Pending Reviews* cuando el usuario no tiene nada que revisar? Se debe dejar asi, tal y como esta? ¿Se debe pedir que se cambie la configuración para nuestro stack, para que se comporte de la manera previa a este cambio? ¿O es este comportamiento un *bug* nuevo, no relacionado, por los posts mencionados?

En definitiva, ¿qué queremos hacer con este problema por el que te sale a veces el indicador de posts pendientes en la cola de revisión cuando en verdad no hay nada?

Comment: El CM Jon Ericson trabajó intensamente en este campo, intentando ajustarlo lo más posible teniendo en cuenta las múltiples variables: permisos de cada usuario, caché, etc. Ha dejado la empresa y dudo que nadie de los que quedan tenga tiempo actualmente para tratarlo, aún menos para ajustar el comportamiento para un sitio concreto. Yo recomiendo ir directamente a /review para ver qué hay, pues la cantidad de falsos positivos es bastante grande.

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinion, se debe pedir que se cambie la configuración para nuestro stack, para que se comporte de la manera previa a este cambio.

Tal vez es un nuevo bug, pero mientras tanto, regresar al estado anterior sería más rápido que esperar que se investigue y resuelva el bug.

Efectivamente, la ruedita roja me confunde, y me afecta.  Así no chequeo la lista de revisiones tan seguido que quisiera hacer.